# Is there a way to make addition of two contiguos columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, frame

I have a data frame where each observation is comprehended in two columns. In this way, columns 1 and 2 represents the individual 1, 3 and 4 the individual 2 and so on.

Basically what I want to do is to add two contigous columns so I have the individual real score.

In this example V1 and V2 represent individual I and V3 and V4 represent individual II. So for the result data frame I will have the half of columns, the same number of rows and each value will be the addition of each value between two contigous colums.

**Data**

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  0  0  1  1
2  1  0  0  0
3  0  1  1  1
4  0  1  0  1
```

**Desire Output**

```
  I II
1 0  2
2 1  0
3 1  2
4 1  1
```

I tried something like this

```
a <- data.frame(V1= c(0,1,0,0),V2=c(0,0,1,1),V3=c(1,0,1,0),V4=c(1,0,1,1))
b <- data.frame(NA, nrow = nrow(a), ncol = ncol(data))
for (i in seq(2,ncol(a),by=2)){
  for (k in 1:nrow(a)){
    b[k,i] <- a[k,i] + a[k,i-1]
  }
}
b <- as.data.frame(b)
b <- b[,-c(seq(1,length(b),by=2))]
```

Is there a way to make it simplier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `split.default` to split the data and then do `rowSums` by looping over the `list`

```
sapply(split.default(a, as.integer(gl(ncol(a), 2, ncol(a)))), rowSums)
     1 2
[1,] 0 2
[2,] 1 0
[3,] 1 2
[4,] 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use vector recycling to select columns and add them.

```
res <- a[c(TRUE, FALSE)] + a[c(FALSE, TRUE)]
names(res) <- paste0('col', seq_along(res))
res
#  col1 col2
#1    0    2
#2    1    0
#3    1    2
#4    1    1
```

Answer (score 1):

dplyr's approach with row-wise operations (rowwise is a special type of grouping per row)

```
a <- data.frame(V1= c(0,1,0,0),V2=c(0,0,1,1),V3=c(1,0,1,0),V4=c(1,0,1,1))

library(dplyr)

a%>%
  rowwise()%>%
  transmute(I=sum(c(V1,V2)),
            II=sum(c(V3,V4)))
```

or alternatively with a built-in row-wise variant of the sum

```
a %>% transmute(I = rowSums(across(1:2)),
                II = rowSums(across(3:4)))
```